# Menu-item to show a navigationdrawer and a back arrow to return

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I want that the back icon in the toolbar is on the left side and it returns to the previous page. And the menu icon in the toolbar should be on the right side and to show the navigationdrawer.

I already have:

[image]

**My code**:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar=(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    //drawerlayout
    mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main3);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,mToolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("NOSTRILS");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by making a lot of changes to code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private EndDrawerToggle drawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        /* Toolbar */
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nostrils");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        // Back icon
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        initNavigationDrawer();
    }


        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main3);

        drawerToggle = new EndDrawerToggle(this,
                drawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.open,
                R.string.close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

        // Back icon clicked
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```